# Change canvas shape

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

What I'd like to achieve: I need to load different images in different canvas, move and resize them and show a preview. I'm using fabricJs. With rectangular canvas everything works fine, the problem is when I want to concatenate canvas with a diagonal section. Something like this:

[image]

I tried something with the transform property in CSS, but then I could no longer interract with the canvas. Any idea on how to do this? Or is there a way to have only one canvas with something like sections?

What I have right now (only part of the code to interract with the canvas, the preview it's another canvas where I draw again everything):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 addImage('canvas1', 'imageLoader1');
 addImage('canvas2', 'imageLoader2');
});         
            
function addImage(canvas, input) {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);
    document.getElementById(input).addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (f) {
            var data = f.target.result;                    
            fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
                var oImg = img.set({
                    left: 0, 
                    top: 0, 
                    angle: 00,
                    width: 100, 
                    height: 100
                }).scale(0.9);
                canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
                var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
                    format: 'png', 
                    quality: 0.8
                });
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 544px;
}

.canvas-container {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.12/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="272px" height="465px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="272px" height="465px" style="float: left;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader1" name="imageLoader1"/>
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader2" name="imageLoader1"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The only way to do this is to have two canvases and only use a portion of each one (cut off by a diagonal).

Comment: @VSO How can I cut the canvases? Should I wrap them inside a div and cut it or is there another way?

Comment: check function clipTo(); you can overlay 2 canvases and clip them http://jsfiddle.net/5FPJt/104/

Comment: @Observer Thanks you! Just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

In reply to @Observer comment:

`clipTo` is [deprecated since `v2.0.0`](http://fabricjs.com/changes-introduction). You could achieve this with [`clipPath`](http://fabricjs.com/clippath-part1) (which is more powerful and more flexible than `clipTo` since it accepts a `fabric.Object`):

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3"})

const container = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
})

const obj = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 50,
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  fill: "blue"
})

canvas.clipPath = container
canvas.add(obj)

canvas.requestRenderAll()
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.0.0-beta.5/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```