# Add style to `clipPath` Fabric.js Object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need a canvas with a specific shape. I was able to do so thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529826/change-canvas-shape) using `clipPath`. The problem is I can't style it at all.

Here an example with a circle shaped canvas. I try to apply the same style to the object inside the container and to the container itself, but as you can see only the object inside the container is styled. How can I apply a stroke or a shadow to this circle container (`clipPath`)?

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3"})

const container = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 150,
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  stroke: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
  strokeWidth: 1,
})

const obj = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  fill: "blue",
  stroke: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
  strokeWidth: 1,
})

const shadow = new fabric.Shadow({
  color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
  blur: 10,
})

container.set("shadow", shadow)
obj.set("shadow", shadow)

canvas.clipPath = container
canvas.add(obj)

canvas.requestRenderAll()
```

```css
#canvas {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.0.0-beta.5/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

[EDIT] I found a company who does that: https://www.plaqueomatic.fr/plaqueomatic/plastique. They use fabric `v3.6.0`. How can I achieve the same?

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the company used shadow on clipPath object? Is there any code you've saw? Because, when I removed the line `canvas.clipPath = container`, then it seems that your styles works on container too. Maybe it's what going on the site too. No?

Comment: I don't know if they use shadow, I just assume based on my knowledge of the tool. I'm open to any other kind of solution. If you remove the line `canvas.clipPath = container`, then you don't have a clipPath anymore. My aim is to change the shape of my canvas. The best way I've found is with `clipPath` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529826/change-canvas-shape), but I can't apply a single style on it.

Comment: What kind of styling are you wanting on your canvas? If it's just a shadow, why not just do it with css? (eg. `filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px #000);`

Comment: Thank you @melchiar, I didn't think it could work! Since there is nothing between the container and the canvas, the [`drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) works perfectly. Could you post as an answer?

Comment: No problem! Just an FYI that if you want to stroke the canvas as well it's a bit more tricky but not impossible. One way would be to size the canvas the same as the clippath and then apply a css border with a 50% radius. Another way would be to add a circle object to the canvas itself with a stroke and let that be the border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When clipping the canvas itself, styles like dropshadows are best applied using CSS. I've also enabled the `controlsAboveOverlay` property to make the resizing controls visible outside the clippath (feel free to disable if you don't need that).

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
  backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
  controlsAboveOverlay: true
})

const container = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 150,
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  stroke: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
  strokeWidth: 1,
})

const obj = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  fill: "blue",
  stroke: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
  strokeWidth: 1,
})

const shadow = new fabric.Shadow({
  color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
  blur: 10,
})

obj.set("shadow", shadow)

canvas.clipPath = container
canvas.add(obj)

canvas.requestRenderAll()
```

```css
#canvas {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.0.0-beta.5/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```